# Combine two rows into one in a csv file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to combine multiple rows in a csv file together. I could easily do it in Excel but I want to do this for hundreds of files so I need it to be as a code. I have tried to store rows in arrays but it doesn't seem to work. I am using Python to do it.

So lets say I have a csv file;

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

All I want to do is to have a csv file as this;

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

The code I have tried is this;

```
fin = open("C:\\1.csv", 'r+')
fout = open("C:\\2.csv",'w')
for line in fin.xreadlines():
  new = line.replace(',', ' ', 1)
  fout.write (new)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Please show your attempt that didn't work so we can help you understand what went wrong

Comment: So I have tried this but I don't think it is right

fin = open("C:\\1.csv", 'r+')
fout = open("C:\\2.csv",'w')
for line in fin.xreadlines():
    new = line.replace(',', ' ', 1)
    fout.write (new)
fin.close()
fout.close()

Comment: It's really not possible to read code in comments, please edit it into your original question with code formatting.

Comment: Sorry for this, I am new to here. I have edited my original question and added the code. Thanks

Comment: No worries :) Working on an answer; you should be using the csv module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for this as splitting CSV manually on commas is very error-prone (single columns can contain strings with commas, but you would incorrectly end up splitting this into multiple columns). The CSV module uses lists of values to represent single rows.

```
import csv

def return_contents(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        return list(reader)

data1 = return_contents('csv1.csv')
data2 = return_contents('csv2.csv')

print(data1)
print(data2)

combined = []
for row in data1:
    combined.extend(row)

for row in data2:
    combined.extend(row)

with open('csv_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(combined)
```

That code gives you the basis of the approach but it would be ugly to extend this for hundreds of files. Instead, you probably want [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to pull all the files in a single directory, one by one, and add them to your output. This is the reason that I packed the reading code into the `return_contents` function; we can repeat the same process millions of times on different files with only one set of code to do the actual reading. Something like this:

```
import csv
import os


def return_contents(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        return list(reader)

all_files = os.listdir('my_csvs')

combined_output = []

for file in all_files:
    data = return_contents('my_csvs/{}'.format(file))
    for row in data:
        combined_output.extend(row)

with open('csv_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(combined_output)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are specially dealing with csv file format. I recommend you to use csv package for the file operations. If you also use `with`...`as` statement, you don't need to worry about closing the file etc. You just need to define the `PATH` then program will iterate all `.csv` files
Here is what you can do:

```
PATH = "your folder path"
def order_list():
      data_list = []
      for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
          if filename.endswith(".csv"):
              with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
                  read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
                  for row in read_csv:
                      data_list.extend(row)

  print(data_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    order_list()
```

Comment: This doesn't show how it can be done for multiple files. The OP mentions that they have hundreds.

Comment: @roganjosh Hi, I have edited my answer. I would be glad if you can suggest or improve. Best Regards

Comment: I extended mine to show how you could use `os.listdir` and package the CSV reading code into a function to avoid all of the nesting.

Answer (score 1):

Store your data in pandas df

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Store the modified dataframe into new one

```
df_2 = df.groupby('Column_Name').agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index() ## Write Name of your column
```

Write the df to new csv

```
df2.to_csv("file_modified.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it also like this:

```
fIn = open("test.csv", "r")
fOut = open("output.csv", "w")

fOut.write(",".join([line for line in fIn]).replace("\n",""))

fIn.close()
fOut.close()
```

I've you want now to run it on multiple file you can run it as script with arguments:

```
import sys
fIn = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
fOut = open(sys.argv[2], "w")

fOut.write(",".join([line for line in fIn]).replace("\n",""))

fIn.close()
fOut.close()
```

So now expect you use some Linux System and the script is called `csvOnliner.py` you could call it with:

```
for i in *.csv; do python csvOnliner.py $i changed_$i; done
```

With windows you could do it in a way like this:

```
FOR %i IN (*.csv) DO csvOnliner.py %i changed_%i
```